# Undefined symbols when linking against libthrift

Tags: c++, macos, thrift

So, I'm trying to utilize thrift, and decided to generate a C++ server. I am using CLion, clang and CMake to compile the project. However, when I try to compile the generated thrift server, it complains about missing symbols at the linking stage..

The linkage error is related to these symbols that I found using `nm`:

```
0000000000000160 T __ZN6apache6thrift5async25TConcurrentClientSyncInfo10getPendingERNSt3__112basic_stringIcNS3_11char_traitsIcEENS3_9allocatorIcEEEERNS0_8protocol12TMessageTypeERi
0000000000000250 T __ZN6apache6thrift5async25TConcurrentClientSyncInfo13updatePendingERKNSt3__112basic_stringIcNS3_11char_traitsIcEENS3_9allocatorIcEEEENS0_8protocol12TMessageTypeEi
```

My main problem is that I have no idea how to proceed. The symbol seems there, and the code causing errors is generated by the thrift tool, not me.

Here is the relevant info:

```
OS X 10.11.4
CMake 3.3
Apple LLVM version 7.3.0 (clang-703.0.29)
```

CMakeLists.txt:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.3)
project(KodLogicDaemon)


include_directories(
    /usr/local/include
    ../Vendor/kod-logic
)

link_directories(
    /usr/local/Cellar/thrift/0.9.3/lib
)


set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -stdlib=libstdc++")

set(SOURCE_FILES

    main.cpp

    Thrift/DKLogic.cpp
    Thrift/interface_types.cpp
)

add_executable(KodLogicDaemon ${SOURCE_FILES})
target_link_libraries(KodLogicDaemon thrift KodLogic)
```

Error:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "apache::thrift::async::TConcurrentClientSyncInfo::getPending(std::string&, apache::thrift::protocol::TMessageType&, int&)", referenced from:
      DKLogicConcurrentClient::recv_calculateBestMove(TMove&, int) in DKLogic.cpp.o
      DKLogicConcurrentClient::recv_validateMove(int) in DKLogic.cpp.o
  "apache::thrift::async::TConcurrentClientSyncInfo::updatePending(std::string const&, apache::thrift::protocol::TMessageType, int)", referenced from:
      DKLogicConcurrentClient::recv_calculateBestMove(TMove&, int) in DKLogic.cpp.o
      DKLogicConcurrentClient::recv_validateMove(int) in DKLogic.cpp.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
make[2]: *** [KodLogicDaemon/KodLogicDaemon] Error 1
make[1]: *** [KodLogicDaemon/CMakeFiles/KodLogicDaemon.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

Comment: Please post that problem into the [user's mailing list](https://thrift.apache.org/mailing)

Comment: @JensG Thanks, wanted to make sure I wasn't missing something obvious outside of thrift.

Comment: I don't know, maybe you do. I did not say anything about that. But chances are you find someone else who did run into the same problem and may be able to help you.

Comment: I always like to make sure to bring closure, so: I ended up mounting a docker container to compile and run, which worked but the `TSimpleServer` server didn't. After more wasted hours, I switched it to `TThreadedServer`, and finally got some results. Then, whenever the C++ server threw an error, it would bring down the whole thing, as well as the client. All these issues made me lose faith in Thrift, so I switched to erlport, connected it to Python, and connected Python to C. The question remains for people interested in resolving this issue.

Comment: What do you do when you run into problems there as well? Switch again? Just asking.

Comment: @JensG That's a fair point! And the answer is yes. I started with ZMQ, actually, which didn't go well at all, since there wasn't a good Elixir implementation. Then, found thrift, which was amazing on Elixir, thanks to the riffed library, but C++ side was a nightmare. I was prepared to gradually move towards more "expensive" options, time-wise or budget-wise, till I find the right tool. If Python hadn't served me well, I would have implemented my own TCP server, TCP client, and that is a chore to write and maintain, but would be a better option than introduce frail dependencies.